# How to display form in centre without scroll bar and blank area

Tags: html, css, forms, alignment

I am using this CSS to display Forms in center of the screen.

```
.Absolute-Center 
{
    width: 40%;
    height: 50%;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Different forms have different number of elements. For example say Login Form have 4 elements, and Forgot password form have 2 elements and form-3 have 12 elements.

For me Login Form is display perfectly. PassWord Form showing some blank area in Bottom. and form-3 showing scroll bar to see bottom elements.

I don't want Blank area or scroll bar in any of the form.

What changes needed in this CSS Class to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the commented out lines:

```
.Absolute-Center {
    width: 40%;
    /* height: auto; */
    /* overflow: auto; */
    margin: auto;
    position: fixed;
    /* top: 0; */
    /* left: 0; */
    /* bottom: 0; */
    /* right: 0; */
}
```

Setting the height to 50% means that the height of the form will be fixed to 50% of the height of its container and setting overflow to auto means that if the form is to big to fit in that height, you'll get a scroll bar.  By removing these lines, you'll allow the browser to set the height of the form based on the content.  You'll also want to removed the top and bottom properties, as these stretch the div over the entire page.

Comment: But in this case all the form are displaying equal to height of screen. Hence blank area can be seen in bottom of form.

Comment: Are you able to show me webpage in question?  I'll be able to be more helpful if I can see what is going wrong.

Comment: you can check the behavior on opening grocerywww.com and click on login. Then password and signup

Comment: Ah yes, you'll need to removed a few other lines.  Just edited my post.

Comment: Removing this /*top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;*/ not even displaying the form.